How there are transactions that are immediately being confirmed/proceed?
I have made bot on NodeJS and also on Rust that they both are doing the same,
Tried both with the nodes that are considered the best at the market that first block guys are using.
The bots are creating swap transaction and sending it, tried also sending like 25/50/100 batch transactions all with skipPreFlight: true and preFlightCommitment: “confirmed” but around same results I get only 1 out of 5/10 tokens that I try to snipe (it’s not even buying minutes after the launch) to get a successful swap even if I pay 500k priority fee.
I have used before some public bot and it’s buying immediately.
Anyone has clue what could be the reason and how to get it better?
My code is sending the transaction with confirmed commitment and once in 2 minutes I get updated blockhash with also confirmed commitment
